# Rails has_many :through with namespace - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm having some trouble defining a has_many :through relationship in Rails 5 where the join and target models both reside within a namespace. I have a `Student` model that I want to join to `Admission::Application` through `Admission::ApplicationStudent`. When I attempt to access the `admission_applications` association I get a NameError: "uninitialized constant Student::Application".

Here are my model definitions:

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :admission_application_students,
    class_name: 'Admission::ApplicationStudent',
    inverse_of: :student
  has_many :admission_applications,
    through: :admission_application_students,
    source: :application
end
```

**admission/application_student.rb**

```
class Admission::ApplicationStudent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :student,
    class_name: 'Student',
    inverse_of: :admission_application_students
end
```

**admission/application.rb**

```
class Admission::Application < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :application_students
  has_many :students,
    through: :application_students,
    source: :student
end
```

Incidentally, I generated all three models with standard commands:

```
rails g model student
rails g model 'Admission::Application'
rails g model 'Admission::ApplicationStudent'
```

The `application_students` and `students` associations are both functioning correctly from `Application`. I can also retrieve a collection of `ApplicationStudent` records from the `admission_application_students` association on `Student`. If `Student` knows how to make it that far, it seems like `:source` has to be the problem, but I've been researching and testing since yesterday, and I no longer feel like I'm making progress. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the `class_name` for `admission_applications` association since it is also in a different namespace:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :admission_application_students, class_name: 'Admission::ApplicationStudent'
  has_many :admission_applications, 
                 through: :admission_application_students, 
                  source: :application, 
              class_name: 'Admission::Application'
end
```

For more information see the documentation for [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) and Section 3.4 Controlling Association Scope of the [Active Record Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: You're absolutely correct and I thank you. I could swear I read somewhere that :class_name is ignored when using :source. Am I crazy to think that the class name could be inferred here? ApplicationStudent already knows how to resolve the application association referenced by :source. This feels like a rare breakdown in the magic of Rails.